# Pass values from my Json (Node.js + Express) to my final app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, frontend, backend

Im trying to build a Datacenter floorplan heatmap, based on this
https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/
and pulling data from some physical sensors I have.

I've amateur experience with backend (NodeJS + Express) and also in HTML/CSS
currently I was able to successfully:

1- Retrieve data from the sensors using Python
2- Save that data into a SQLite Database
3- connect to this database using nodejs+express and make a working router that shows a json in the assigned route with the values I need (Ej: Sensor 1, Sensor 2 & time)

Now, I've a working API but my problem is that the heatmap works with values on certain variables (ej: point 1: 20.4 & point 2:20.6) on the HTML file that integrates with the javascript.

How can I pass this values from my backend to my html page to assign the value to those points? I don't have any knowledge integrating backend with frontend, so any suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code or knowing your exact implementation, maybe this can give you a rough idea of how to get this working:

```
// server-side

app.get('/sensorData', (req, res, next) => {
  // DB code to retrieve all sensor data, I assume you have this implemented somehow already and are returning the data as json at some endpoint
  SensorData.getAllSensorData((data) => {
    res.json(data);
  });
});

// client-side

fetch('/sensorData')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(sensorData => {
    const dataPoints = sensorData.map(dataPoint => {
      return {
        x: datapoint.x, // or whatever you've named the x-value
        y: datapoint.y,
        value: // whatever the heatmap value is
      };
    });
    heatmapInstance.addData(dataPoints);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! in what language should I write that client-side or how is client supposed to get the website? I have to install react? Of course I don't want you to solve it for me, just to give me a hint. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Last Update: I used javascript and was able to get that Json on the console! Thanks Daniel, I'm gonna keep investigating from this point so I can learn how to fully implement. Have a nice day!